# When to use what

Tags: pronouns, questions

It is correct to say

> What FRIENDS were you hanging out with ?
>
> What AMERICAN AUTHOR wrote series of books about a .....?

I find t weird to ask these questions but I read it in a book.

Comment: I think you mean "whose friend"

Comment: Please clarity why exactly you find these questions weird.

Comment: How do you believe these sentences should be written? BTW - "what" could be replaced with "which" here, and it would be almost the same. not exactly.